# Django ModelForm is_valid = False but errors empty

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am banging my head for two days over a simple issue I believe!

Simple Model:

```
class CryptoOptions(models.Model):
    setting_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dictionary=models.TextField()
    alphabet=models.TextField()
    criteria_types = (('ASCII', 'ASCII set'),
                                        ('EN', 'English language'),
                                        ('CUSTOM', 'Custom criteria'),
                                )
    criteria=models.CharField(max_length = 32, choices=criteria_types, default='ASCII')

    operation_types = (('xor', 'XOR'),
                                         ('ror', 'Rotation Right'),
                                         ('rol', 'Rotation Left'),
                                         ('shiftl', 'Shift Left'),
                                         ('shiftr', 'Shift Right'),
                                         ('rot13', 'Rotation 13'),
                                         ('base64', 'Base 64')
                                    )
    operation = models.CharField(max_length = 32, choices=operation_types, default='xor')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.setting_name)
```

Simple ModelForm:

```
class CryptoOptionsForm(ModelForm):
    optionid= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CryptoOptions.objects.all(),initial=0)
    class Meta:
        model = CryptoOptions
        fields = ['dictionary', 'alphabet', 'criteria','operation']
```

In the View:

```
xoratorForm=None

if request.method == 'POST':

    if 'optionid' in request.POST:

        if request.POST['optionid'].isdigit():
            defaultOption=CryptoOptions.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST['optionid' ]))
            xoratorForm=CryptoOptionsForm(instance=defaultOption)
            xoratorForm.fields['optionid'].initial=int(request.POST['optionid'])
            if xoratorForm.is_valid():
                print "Valid"
                print xoratorForm.cleand_data
            else:
                print "Errors"
                print xoratorForm.errors
```

The request.POST is fully filled:

```
<QueryDict: {u'dictionary': [u'Windows\r\nCopyright\r\nSystem32'], u'alphabet': [u'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'], u'optionid': [u'1'], u'criteria': [u'ASCII'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'QsSHIMhYgANR0a5a1FJ9gCLey5DcAINp'], u'operation': [u'xor']}>
```

The DjangoForm seems also filled with values.

I am not sure what is going on here, any way to debug?

The other way works:

```
defaultOption=CryptoOptions.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST['optionid' ]))
print defaultOption
#xoratorForm=CryptoOptionsForm(instance=defaultOption)
#xoratorForm.fields['optionid'].initial=int(request.POST['optionid'])
xoratorForm=CryptoOptionsForm(request.POST,instance=defaultOption)
```

but that's not my intended purpose as I want to change the form from the defaultOption rather than the submitted form.
It probably doesn't like the fact that I am passing the Meta object rather then the entire object including the multiple choice field?

I am Django newbie!

Last discovery today was trying to override the methods in such a way:

```
class CryptoOptionsForm(ModelForm):
    optionid= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CryptoOptions.objects.all(),initial=0)
    class Meta:
        model = CryptoOptions
        fields = ['dictionary', 'alphabet', 'criteria','operation']


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if kwargs.get('instance'):
            print "Instance INIT"
            if isinstance(kwargs['instance'],CryptoOptions):
                object = kwargs['instance']
                kwargs.setdefault('initial', {})['optionid'] = object.pk
                kwargs.setdefault('initial', {})['model'] = object
        else:
            print "POST INIT"
        print kwargs
        return super(CryptoOptionsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

But again form does not validate.
Not sure what I am doing wrong!

Comment: You  have forgotten the `request.POST` argument into the form? `xoratorForm=CryptoOptionsForm(request.POST, instance=defaultOption)`

Comment: What is the issue? Form validates (form.is_valid()) but you can't save the modelform (modelform.save())? Or some other issue

Comment: @karthikr that's not the intended purpose because if I use the request.POST it will load the with the old data, but I want to load the form with the newly selected CryptoOption data.

Comment: @JamesR The form does not validate with the first example, I need to be able to access the cleaned_data field for starting a celerytask. I need to be able to load that defaultOption object (not the old request.POST) and then validate it to retrieve the cleaned_data from the form.

Comment: Was attempting this today:

Comment: Could you try to explain what it is you are trying to accomplish in general. This approach seems complicated and I'm not sure I understand the problem.